# Why is Python reading my function call as a variable call?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, variables

Using Python 2.7.9, this is my code:

```
    def secondaction():
        secondaction = raw_input(prompt)

        if secondaction == "walk through door" or secondaction == "go through door":
        print "Well done! You enter the Treasure Room..."
        treasure_room()

        else:
        print "If you don't go through that door you will never leave this cave."        
        secondaction()

firstact = raw_input(prompt)
global handclenched
def firstaction():
elif firstact == "use sword" and handclenched:
    print "You killed the hand giant! A door appears behind it. What will you do?"
    secondaction()
```

When Powershell takes me to the `secondaction()` function after I enter 'use sword' with 'handclenched' set to `True`, I enter `yh` as the `raw_input()` value and Powershell puts forward this error message:

```
You killed the hand giant! A door appears behind it. What will you do?
> yh
If you don't go through that door you will never leave this cave.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex36game.py", line 168, in <module>
    right_room()
  File "ex36game.py", line 166, in right_room
    firstaction()
  File "ex36game.py", line 147, in firstaction
    firstaction()
  File "ex36game.py", line 153, in firstaction
    secondaction()
  File "ex36game.py", line 136, in secondaction
    secondaction()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

**However** when I change the code to:

```
 def secondaction():
    second_action = raw_input(prompt)

    if second_action == "walk through door" or second_action == "go through door":
    print "Well done! You enter the Treasure Room..."
    treasure_room()

    else:
    print "If you don't go through that door you will never leave this cave."        
    secondaction()
```

It all works fine and I get no error message.

Why can't Python read the `secondaction()` as a function call instead of code that invokes/calls (are those the correct words?) the `secondfunction` variable that `raw_input()` was assigned to?

Comment: Change the variable name. Why name your variable the exact same thing as the function name, all it can do is lead to confusion, as you've seen

Comment: In python, functions are objects, and a function name is just a variable that happens to hold a function. If you reassign that name, it isn't holding your function any more.

Comment: Indeed - I really want to know why this is, given that the function is called with parenthesis. Shouldn't Python be able to tell the difference?

Comment: Also that's the answer to this question - so post it as an answer and I can assign this as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't Python read the 'secondaction()' as a function call instead of code that invokes/calls (are those the correct words?) the 'secondfunction' variable

In Python, functions *are* variables. That is to say, functions are first-class objects, which are assigned to variables by the `def` statement; there is no separate namespace for callable functions vs assignable variables like some languages have.

This means that when you write `secondaction = raw_input(prompt)` you are making a local variable called `secondaction` inside the function. Now when you write `secondaction` anywhere in that function body you are referring to the local variable; writing `secondaction()` with parentheses doesn't get you access to a separate function namespace, it just tries to call the value of the local variable that `secondaction` represents, and strings aren't callable so you get an error.

It also means you can do things like:

```
def foo(x):
    return x+1

>>> bar= foo
>>> lookup= {'thing': bar}
>>> lookup['thing']
<function foo>
>>> lookup['thing'](1)
2
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python, functions are objects, and a function name is just a variable that happens to hold a function. If you reassign that name, it isn't holding your function any more.

Answer (score 1):

Because you redeclaring the name `secondaction = raw_input(prompt)` in local scope.

Take a look at [python-scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote:

```
secondaction = raw_input(prompt)
```

`sectionaction` is now a string, and you can't call a string as if it were a function. A name can't have two meanings at the same time, and the most recent assignment takes precedence, so you have lost the reference to your function. Use a different name for one of them, as you have done in the code that works.

Comment: But don't the parenthesis differentiate between the variable and the function even after 'secondaction' has been assigned again?

Comment: No, `secondaction` is just a name that refers to an object.  Whether that object is a string, or a procedure is irrelevant.  If you define a procedure `secondaction` and then assign `secondaction = 'this and that'`, then `secondaction` no longer refers to the procedure (assuming no namespace business).

Comment: A statement like `simpleaction()` is actually two operations. First, get the object named `simpleaction`, and second, call it. Python doesn't know that the name `secondaction` refers to a function until you perform the call operation on it, at which point it fails if it's not a function. (There are actually other kinds of callable objects, but that'll do for now.) There are not two separate lists, one for functions and one for other kinds of values; a `def` statement is just a fancy `=`.